# How can I add a Mongo Query inside one Document and insert it in a Collection?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

This a sample document. I wish to insert a MongoDB query in the field "condition".

So how to insert it?

```
{
    "_id": 9000001,
    "GeoId": 111002,
    "collection": "Age",
    "condition": "{ db.age.find({"Fields.FieldValue" : ""})}",
    "alertMessageTemplate": "The age is #<20#  & #>100# ",
}
```

Answer (score 1):

My best approach will be collection name and condition is separate fields:

```
"collection": "Age",
"condition": {"Fields.FieldValue" : ""},
```

This way you can save condition as a JSON object.

Then you can format on find: `db.getCollection('+collection+').find('+condition+');`

Comment: Will try this using Java and will check if I can read that query.Thanks